# Why transform.find() does not need actual object[unity]

Tags: unity, c#, unityscript

I m new to unity and C#.

I suspect that transform.find() function below does not need actual object reference like

> player.transform.find()

because it transform find is already applied to the gameObject the script is attached to? Am I right?
Why transform.find() does not have any game object in front of it?

public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour{

```
private Transform groundCheck ;


void Awake()
{
    groundCheck = transform.Find("groundCheck");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transform` is the instance of `Transform` which is a public attribute of `GameObject`. That is why we don't need it. But you can use `gameObject.transform.Find("groundCheck");` though. Similarly `gameObject` is the instance of `GameObject` representing the `GameObject` in which this script is attached.

Comment: Well, actually it'd be because it's a public property of MonoBehaviour, right?

Comment: @Ben Check this http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html